# How to replace all .html url to .html?details=y in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to replace  all .html url to .html?details=y in .htaccess ? I want to replace all the url ending with .html with .html?details=y

in my website all the listing url ending with .html, listing url detail page are html?details=y

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !details=y
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.html?details=y [L,QSA,R]
```